# Working with images when uploading in Adobe Flex

Tags: image, apache-flex, upload, jpeg

I'm beginner with Flex and I already have a hard task to develop, so I could use some help! :)

What I have to do is upload some images to a server, which is OK, but before uploading I must downsize this images by reducing their quality and width/height. I've found many information about the class JPGEncoder, but I couldn't make it work.

Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks!
Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

you can use encodeByteArray() method of JPEGEncoder. [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/graphics/codec/JPEGEncoder.html)

some good article for image uploading to server is available at 
1. [insideRIA](http://www.insideria.com/2008/03/image-manipulation-in-flex.html) 
2. http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder
3. http://blog.pigdev.com/?p=137

Comment: Hi Chinmay,

Thanks for your reply. So far, I've got this:

private function uploadImage():void{
   _netConnection = new NetConnection();
   _netConnection.connect('http://192.168.1.254/teste2.php');
   var res:Responder = new Responder(onDataResult, onDataError);
   _netConnection.call("",res,_imageByteArray);
}

And my PHP "teste2.php" simply opens an file with "w+" permission and implodes the $obj array passed by the above function. But all the script does is create a O bytes .jpg file.

Could you please help e again with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample:

farg.  this code editor leaves a little to be desired...

```
        import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

    private function btnClick(e:Event):void
    {
        var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(0); // Terrible quality
        picNew.source = encoder.encode( Bitmap(picOrig.content).bitmapData );
    }

<mx:Image id="picOrig" x="10" y="10" source="image1.png"/>
<mx:Image id="picNew" x="200" y="10" />
<mx:Button x="100" y="300" label="Button" click="btnClick(event);"/>
```